# Cannot delete file in OS X

Tags: macos, trash

I have a file in trash, and I cannot delete it.  Before you ask me to STFW, no, the file is not locked :-/

The file is a symbolic link to nothing (target is deleted).  Here is the output of `ls -lO` on that file:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1000  _lpoperator  uappnd,nodump,opaque,compressed 22 Apr  3  2009 fly.pdf -> stuff.pdf
```

The output of `rm` is

```
$ sudo rm fly.pdf
rm: fly.pdf: No such file or directory
```

However the file does exist, which can be confirmed by `ls` or by opening trash in Finder.  If I empty trash using the menu, it plays that sound and nothing happens.  If I try securely empty trash, it complains about not having permission.  So I'm stuck... Any suggestion?

BTW, the file in question is in the trash of a volume called "Shared", which is not the boot volume.

UPDATE: @bug pointed out that this may be caused by my link being opaque, and suggested to delete it in a chroot jail.  I tried that, and chroot gave me a segmentation fault.  Here is what I did for that: I enabled root following [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1528), and followed @bug's answer and [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=o9K8KEQic5sC&pg=PA462&lpg=PA462&dq=how+to+chroot+in+mac&source=bl&ots=lWO_Y76djF&sig=OJsu1LqYqE92V6Em4HBD6y5ROlo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Dq0oT__XCsm60AGZ-ZnXAg&ved=0CGoQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=how%20to%20chroot%20in%20mac&f=false) to create the chroot jail.  Chroot gave me

```
# chroot /Volumes/Shared
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: Just tried it within linux, created a symlink, removed the target, no complaints when deleting the link afterwards. strange problem :/

Comment: Exactly.  In my mind sym links are just regular files, so I'm kinda confused...

Comment: @Darksair I think if you use `rm -rf` it will probably also work. :)

Comment: @TheDevil: No I tried, and it didn't :-\, which was pretty weird...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Chflags` has an option `-h` to not follow links (which I constantly ignored...).

```
# chflags -h noopaque,nouappnd,dump fly.pdf
```

And then empty trash.

Comment: How would a file get in this state on its own?

Answer (score 0):

Try dragging the file to the desktop, open a Terminal window, enter your `sudo rm -R` then drag the file to the Terminal window.

I've seen this work before and I'd use the `-R` just in case the file is really a package.

Comment: Here is what happens when I drag that file to anywhere: if the destination is on the same volume as the file in trash, Finder wants to move it.  It asks me for password, and then nothing happens (file not moved); if the destination is on a different volume, Finder wants to copy, and it does that.  I can delete the newly copied file, but the file in trash remains.  And `rm -R` produces the same output as without the `-R`.

Comment: Try this `sudo rm -ri ~/.Trash` then logout and login again.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  However it doesn't seem to fix it :-(  The file in question is in the trash of a volume called "Shared", so I guess I should replace `~/.Trash` with `/Volumes/Shared/.Trashes`, right?  Here is the output: http://pastie.org/3292919 (sorry for an external link, I cannot have multi-line code here..., and yes, my UID is 1001 :-p)

Answer (score 0):

<del>Have you tried `unlink`?  ...</del>

It might be that the symlink is being bypassed because it's `opaque`.  Try removing it from the context of its containing filesystem by setting up a `chroot` jail:

```
cd /Volumes/Shared
mkdir bin
sudo cp /bin/zsh /bin/rm ./bin
chroot /Volumes/Shared
cd .Trashes/1001/abroad
sudo rm fly.pdf
sudo rm -r /bin
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I tried it, and it produces the same output: `unlink: fly.pdf: No such file or directory`...

Comment: Wait a minute...that's an opaque link!  Is your home folder on a different drive/partition than your boot volume?

Comment: The file in question is in the trash of a volume called "Shared", which is not the boot volume, and my home is not on it.  What's an opaque link?  I tried to remove the `opaque` flag with `chflags`, but I couldn't.

Comment: Symlinks marked as `opaque` act like ordinary files when the filesystem they're on is mounted within another filesystem.  I'll edit with a possible solution...

Comment: Chroot complained about not being able to find `/bin/zsh`, which is my login shell.  I also tried `sudo chroot -u root /Volumes/Shared rm .Trashes/1001/abroad/fly.pdf`, and it complained the same thing about `rm`.  Should I somehow link my `/bin` and `/usr/bin` into `/Volumes/Shared` first?

Comment: Oh, right, how silly of me.  The easiest way to do this is actually to just copy the tools you need, since symlinks can't reach outside of a `chroot` jail.  Editing again!

Comment: Ok... I failed.  I copied everything including libraries, and `chroot` gave me a segmentation fault :-<.  STFW-ed but couldn't find anything useful... I'll update my post with some detail.

Comment: I must admit I haven't done anything serious with `chroot`, and I'm not at a machine I have root access to experiment with myself.  I'm still intrigued by this problem, though!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `rm -rf *` while in the trash can not sure if it'l work on your link but worth a try its what I use when files in the trash refuse to delete with empty trash

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I tried it, but it still complains about no such file blabla...